# NLog is not writing when using nlogsettings.json file

Tags: .net-6.0, nlog, ilogger

I am trying to write logs using ILogger from Microsoft.Extensions.Logging and with NLog as a provider. I added a separate nlogsettings.json file to define configuration because to maintain appsettings file as minimum as possible and also to separate the config files during deployments to higher environments.

Here is my `nlosettings.json` where all my nlog configuration setup is defined.

```json
    {
      "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
          "Default": "Information",
          "Microsoft": "Warning",
          "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
        }
      },
      "NLog": {
        "internalLogFile": "c:\\Logs\\internal-nlog.txt",
        "LogLevel": {
          "Default": "Info",
          "Microsoft": "Warn",
          "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
        },
        "extensions": [
          { "assembly": "NLog.Extensions.Logging" },
          { "assembly": "NLog.Web.AspNetCore" }
        ],    
        "Targets": {
          "File": {
            "Type": "File",
            "FileName": "c:\\Logs\\service.log",
            "Layout": "${message}"
          }
        },
        "Rules": [
          {
            "Logger": "*",
            "MinLevel": "Debug",
            "WriteTo": "File"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

Here is my `Program.cs` which is the main entry

```cs
    public class Program
        {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           var logger = LogManager.Setup().LoadConfigurationFromFile("nlogsettings.json").GetCurrentClassLogger();
            logger.Info("Application starts");
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();           
        }
    
        private static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) => Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            }).ConfigureLogging(logging =>
            {
                logging.ClearProviders();
                logging.SetMinimumLevel(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Trace);
            }).UseNLog();
    }
```

Here is my Controller . it is not a fancy controller. Just a GET method is returning OK with a message

```cs
public class InventoryController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ILogger<InventoryController> _logger;        
    public InventoryController(ILogger<InventoryController> logger, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory){_logger = logger;}
    [HttpGet]    
    public async Task<ActionResult> GetInventory()
    {
        await Task.Delay(100);            
        _logger.LogInformation("Testing the nlog log write");
        return Ok("Success");
    }
}
```

But when I debug it is hitting the breakpoint at logger.LogInformation but is not writing to the folder that is specified in nlogsettings.json. I tried different ways changing nlogsettings file. Can someone check and see if I am missing anything in the above set up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LogManager.Setup().LoadConfigurationFromFile` only supports XML-files, and not JSON-files. It is always a good idea to enable [NLog InternalLogger](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging) when [troubleshooting NLog](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logging-troubleshooting).

If you install [NLog.Extensions.Logging](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Extensions.Logging)-nuget-package, then you can do this:

```cs
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(basePath ?? Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("nlogsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .Build();
var logger = LogManager.Setup()
                       .LoadConfigurationFromSection(config)
                       .GetCurrentClassLogger();
```

See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/wiki/NLog-configuration-with-appsettings.json

Comment: This is charm!! I have been struggling with 'LoadConfigurationFromFile' and was thinking it woks for all type of files. Thank you so much for your response.